# How to fix this code written in C?

Tags: c, arrays, text-files

It works perfectly well for a 20-20 table but for anything else it crashes.
the file is in this link:http://www.csd.uoc.gr/~hy100/glid.txt.
I can not figure out what the problem is because when I put an 20-20 table it works and when 
I give a 21-20 table it does the job perfectly fine but crashes before being able to return 0; .

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int height, length;
char **world, **new_world;

int load_world_from_file(char filename[]) {

  int i, j;
  char ch;

  FILE *fp;
  fp = fopen(filename, "r");

  if (fp == NULL ) {
    perror("Error while opening the file.\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  fscanf(fp, "%d %d", &height, &length);
  printf("here:%d,%d\n", height, length);
  /*dilosi dunamika tou pinaka kataxoriseis*/
  /* declaration under the table entries */
  world = (char **) malloc(sizeof(char *) * (height + 1));/*height + 1 ('\0')*/
  for (i = 0; i < 2 * height; i++) {
    /* height + height ('|') + 1    ('\0') */
    world[i] = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * (length + length + 1));
  }

  /* height + 1 ('\0') */
  new_world = (char **) malloc(sizeof(char *) * (height + 1));
  for (i = 0; i < 2 * height; i++) {
    /* height + height ('|') +  1 ('\0') */
    new_world[i] = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * (length + length + 1));
  }

  printf("The contents of %s file are :\n", filename);

  i = 0;
  j = 0;
  while ((ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {
    i++;
    if (i = length + length + 1) {
      j++;
      i = 0;
    }
    world[j] = ch;
    printf("%c", world[j]);
  }
  printf("\n");
  for (i = 0; i < (((2 * length) + 2) * height) + 1; i++) {
    printf("%c", world[i]);
  }

  fclose(fp);
  return 0;
}

int main() {

  char filename[30], filename2[30];

  printf("Enter the name of file you want to open:\n");
  scanf("%s", &filename);

  load_world_from_file(filename);

  return 0;
}
```

Your help is much appreciated.
IT

Comment: `i=length+length+1` should be using `==`. Otherwise `j` will exceed bounds far sooner than expected.

Comment: Thanks. Itfunny because this is a syntax error that i fixed and the problem doesnt work ! It works with something that doesnt even make sense : if(i=length+length+1){

Comment: `world[index](world[j], world[j])` is `char *`. wrong `world[j]=ch;
  printf("%c",world[j]);`

Comment: Also `for(i=0;i<(((2*length)+2)*height)+1;i++){printf("%c",world[i]);
}` is wrong. `world[k]`s are contiguous but NOT `*world[k]`s. You should be using two variables (eg, world[i][j]).

Comment: He means `%c` is for `char` but `world[j]` type is `char*`! And `%s` won't help because you didn't add null character at end of each row or initialize with null characters.

Comment: one line : `|c` * 20 + `|` + `'\n'` == 42 , != `lenght + length + 1` (length(20) : 41)

Comment: This is what i thougth too but it would only function properly when there was 2 instead of an 1 !

Comment: That's because if you are on Windows, there might also be a '\r' along with the '\n'.  If you want null terminated strings, you need extra +1 characters.